# How to construct a confusion matrix when cross-validating with k-NN in R

Tags: r, r-caret, nearest-neighbor, rpart

I tried to ask this question on the other forum but after receiving no answer, I'm reformulating it here and being a bit more specific about my problem. I've a dataset looking like this:

```
> head(knnresults)
   ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z classification
1:         40         47         62        Feeding
2:         60         74         95       Standing
3:         62         63         88       Standing
4:         60         56         82       Standing
5:         66         61         90       Standing
6:         60         53         80       Standing
```

With the column `classification` having three different categories `Feeding`, `Standing` and `Foraging`.

I'm now selecting an optimal `k` value, reason why I'm classifying 20% of the data using the other 80% as training. The classification is based on the values in the first three columns. The `k` value showing the highest accuracy will be selected for future classification analysis.

Here's the script I've been using for this matter:

```
library(ISLR)
library(caret)
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)

# Split the data for cross validation:
indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = knnresults$classification,p = 0.8,list = FALSE)
training <- knnresults[indxTrain,]
testing <- knnresults[-indxTrain,]

# Run k-NN:
set.seed(400)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3)
knnFit <- train(classification ~ ., data = training, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"),tuneLength = 20)
knnFit

#Plotting different k values against accuracy (based on repeated cross validation)
plot(knnFit)
```

First, let me apologize as I'm new to R and I'm unsure about the legitimacy of this script. I will be very glad to accept any suggestion of correction in case errors are spotted.

Second, how do I access a confusion matrix of classification based on this code? This is important in order to calculate performance metrics associated with the classification.

I can `dput()` my dataset below if that can help:

```
> dput(knnresults)
structure(list(ACTIVITY_X = c(40L, 60L, 62L, 60L, 66L, 60L, 57L, 
54L, 52L, 93L, 80L, 14L, 61L, 51L, 40L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 53L, 48L, 
73L, 73L, 21L, 29L, 63L, 59L, 57L, 51L, 53L, 67L, 72L, 74L, 70L, 
60L, 74L, 85L, 77L, 68L, 58L, 80L, 34L, 45L, 34L, 60L, 75L, 62L, 
66L, 51L, 53L, 48L, 62L, 62L, 57L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 23L, 5L, 4L, 
0L, 13L, 45L, 44L, 31L, 68L, 88L, 43L, 70L, 18L, 83L, 71L, 67L, 
75L, 74L, 49L, 90L, 44L, 64L, 57L, 22L, 29L, 52L, 37L, 32L, 120L, 
45L, 22L, 54L, 30L, 9L, 27L, 14L, 3L, 29L, 12L, 61L, 60L, 29L, 
15L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
23L, 49L, 46L, 8L, 31L, 45L, 60L, 37L, 61L, 52L, 51L, 38L, 86L, 
60L, 41L, 43L, 40L, 42L, 42L, 48L, 64L, 71L, 59L, 0L, 27L, 12L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 21L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 46L, 46L, 59L, 53L, 
37L, 44L, 39L, 49L, 37L, 47L, 17L, 36L, 32L, 33L, 26L, 12L, 8L, 
31L, 35L, 27L, 27L, 24L, 17L, 35L, 39L, 28L, 54L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 17L, 22L, 25L, 12L, 0L, 5L, 41L, 51L, 66L, 39L, 32L, 
53L, 43L, 40L, 44L, 45L, 48L, 51L, 41L, 45L, 39L, 46L, 59L, 31L, 
5L, 24L, 18L, 5L, 15L, 13L, 0L, 26L, 0L), ACTIVITY_Y = c(47L, 
74L, 63L, 56L, 61L, 53L, 40L, 41L, 49L, 32L, 54L, 13L, 99L, 130L, 
38L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 94L, 96L, 38L, 43L, 29L, 47L, 66L, 47L, 38L, 
31L, 36L, 35L, 38L, 72L, 54L, 44L, 45L, 51L, 80L, 48L, 39L, 85L, 
42L, 39L, 37L, 75L, 36L, 45L, 32L, 35L, 41L, 26L, 99L, 163L, 
124L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 37L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 29L, 29L, 26L, 27L, 54L, 
147L, 82L, 98L, 12L, 83L, 97L, 104L, 128L, 81L, 42L, 102L, 60L, 
79L, 58L, 15L, 14L, 75L, 75L, 40L, 130L, 40L, 13L, 54L, 42L, 
7L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 15L, 8L, 75L, 55L, 26L, 18L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 45L, 38L, 10L, 31L, 
52L, 36L, 65L, 97L, 45L, 59L, 49L, 92L, 51L, 34L, 21L, 20L, 29L, 
28L, 22L, 32L, 30L, 86L, 0L, 15L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 72L, 62L, 98L, 55L, 26L, 39L, 28L, 81L, 20L, 
52L, 12L, 48L, 24L, 40L, 30L, 5L, 6L, 40L, 37L, 33L, 26L, 17L, 
14L, 39L, 27L, 28L, 67L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 
0L, 2L, 39L, 67L, 74L, 28L, 23L, 57L, 34L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 46L, 
43L, 73L, 65L, 31L, 64L, 128L, 17L, 3L, 12L, 17L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 
0L, 17L, 0L), ACTIVITY_Z = c(62L, 95L, 88L, 82L, 90L, 80L, 70L, 
68L, 71L, 98L, 97L, 19L, 116L, 140L, 55L, 24L, 22L, 7L, 108L, 
107L, 82L, 85L, 36L, 55L, 91L, 75L, 69L, 60L, 64L, 76L, 81L, 
103L, 88L, 74L, 87L, 99L, 111L, 83L, 70L, 117L, 54L, 60L, 50L, 
96L, 83L, 77L, 73L, 62L, 67L, 55L, 117L, 174L, 136L, 5L, 1L, 
27L, 44L, 5L, 7L, 0L, 32L, 54L, 51L, 41L, 87L, 171L, 93L, 120L, 
22L, 117L, 120L, 124L, 148L, 110L, 65L, 136L, 74L, 102L, 81L, 
27L, 32L, 91L, 84L, 51L, 177L, 60L, 26L, 76L, 52L, 11L, 29L, 
14L, 3L, 33L, 14L, 97L, 81L, 39L, 23L, 7L, 14L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
1L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 29L, 67L, 60L, 13L, 44L, 69L, 
70L, 75L, 115L, 69L, 78L, 62L, 126L, 79L, 53L, 48L, 45L, 51L, 
50L, 53L, 72L, 77L, 104L, 0L, 31L, 14L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 24L, 
7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 85L, 77L, 114L, 76L, 45L, 59L, 48L, 95L, 
42L, 70L, 21L, 60L, 40L, 52L, 40L, 13L, 10L, 51L, 51L, 43L, 37L, 
29L, 22L, 52L, 47L, 40L, 86L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 25L, 29L, 
14L, 0L, 5L, 57L, 84L, 99L, 48L, 39L, 78L, 55L, 54L, 57L, 58L, 
66L, 67L, 84L, 79L, 50L, 79L, 141L, 35L, 6L, 27L, 25L, 5L, 17L, 
15L, 0L, 31L, 0L), classification = c("Feeding", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Foraging", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Feeding", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Feeding", "Standing", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Feeding", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Foraging", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Feeding", "Standing", "Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Standing", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Foraging", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Foraging", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", 
"Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Standing", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", 
"Feeding", "Feeding", "Foraging", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Standing", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", 
"Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Feeding", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging", 
"Foraging", "Foraging", "Foraging")), row.names = c(NA, -215L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002531ef0>)
```

Any input is truly appreciated!

Comment: Well, don't you need to `predict` first?!

Comment: You'll need to compare your predictions with your actual classifications to arrive at a confusion matrix. Your data only seems to have the classification and not the prediction.

Comment: use `savePredictions = "final"` in `trainControl` this will return predictions for the hold out predictions in `knnFit` so you can calculate any metric your desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(caret)
train_set<-createDataPartition(iris$Species,p=0.8,list=FALSE)
valid_set<-iris[-train_set,]
train_set<-iris[train_set,]
ctrl<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
set.seed(233)
mk<-train(Species~.,data=train_set,method="knn",trControl = ctrl,metric="Accuracy")
```

Getting a confusion matrix. Ideally, it is better to compare your training to `predict`ed values of the test or validation set.

**Edit**:
To retrieve the table, simply do:

```
confusionMatrix(mk)["table"]
$table
            Reference
Prediction       setosa versicolor  virginica
  setosa     33.3333333  0.0000000  0.0000000
  versicolor  0.0000000 32.5000000  2.5000000
  virginica   0.0000000  0.8333333 30.8333333
```

**Original**

```
 confusionMatrix(mk)
```

Result:

```
Cross-Validated (5 fold) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)

            Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa       33.3        0.0       0.0
  versicolor    0.0       31.7       1.7
  virginica     0.0        1.7      31.7

 Accuracy (average) : 0.9667
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. However, as mentionned in my original post, I'll be using the confusion matrix to calculate performance metrics. How can I extract the values from the confusion matrix you provide? I'm trying to use:`> confMat<-confusionMatrix(knnFit)
> confMat<-as.table(confMat)
Error in as.table.default(confMat) : cannot coerce to a table` but as you can see I get an error.